# redirect old urls without index.php and parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I was able to get my old URL's with index.php to redirect to my new clean URL's

eg: example.com/index.php?gender=m&height=70&weight=150
to
example.com/men/70-inches/150-lbs/

However I've been trying to hack my way getting the other URL's without the index.php to also redirect to the clean url

eg: example.com/?gender=m&height=70&weight=150
to
example.com/men/70-inches/150-lbs/

my current redirection for URL's with index.php that works looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?gender=m&height=([0-9-]+)&weight=([0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /men/%1-inches/%2-lbs/? [L,R=301]
```

I've tried this, for URL's without index.php but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?gender=m&height=([0-9-]+)&weight=([0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^/$ /men/%1-inches/%2-lbs/? [L,R=301]
```

Problem is google has indexed a bunch of my page with the `example.com/?gender=m&height=70&weight=150`  and I want to have them all pointing to the one clean URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct idea, but your rewrite rule's pattern won't work: `^/$`. The URI's sent through rules in an htaccess file has the leading slash removed, so there's no `/` URI ever, it'll just be blank:

```
# no slash---v
RewriteRule ^$ /men/%1-inches/%2-lbs/? [L,R=301]
```

So the whole thing should be:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?gender=m&height=([0-9-]+)&weight=([0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /men/%1-inches/%2-lbs/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks again Jon! I need to get off my ass and read more of the htaccess rewrite documentation.